# Geoserver problem rectangular images can not be selected at edges

Tags: geoserver

I have a Geoserver layer that displays some points. Each point has an image_url attribute.

My styling doc is so simple:

```
*
{
  mark-size: 100;
  mark: url("${image_url}"); 
}
```

The problem, as shown in the following video, is that when I add a rectangular image, it can not be selected by clicking on its edges; it can be selected only when clicking on or near the center. This problem doesn't appear in square images.

Here is [the video](https://streamable.com/gd5je)

And here are a sample [rectangular image](https://wow.olympus.eu/webfile/img/1632/x=1024/oly_testwow_stage.jpg), and a [square image](https://assets.fireside.fm/file/fireside-images/podcasts/images/b/bc7f1faf-8aad-4135-bb12-83a8af679756/cover_medium.jpg)

Comment: What JS renderer are you using, Leaflet, Openlayers? For eg in the case of Openlayers, you need to set the Hit Tolerance property. https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/hit-tolerance.html

Comment: I'm using Openlayers; and I believe that it's not a problem of Hit Tolerance, because square images work perfectly.

Comment: can you add a link to an example image (or add the image to the question)

Comment: @IanTurton I've updated the question. Thanks for your reply.